# Get shape filename in attribute field using field calculator

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, field-calculator

I apologize for crossposting against the ESRI geoprocessing forum, but it seems like this one gets answers. I'd like to have a modified append tool (ArcToolbox) that takes multiple shapefiles with point attribute data, and copies the inputted shapefile's name(s) to a "filename" attribute column, and then appends it to a target dataset. That way I can track where the data came from. The only way I can think to do this is something along the lines of the following:

```
for each shp in featureclasses:
  outFeatureClass = os.path.join("C:\GIS\Scripts\temp\temptrks", shp.strip(".shp"))
  arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(shp, outFeatureClass)
  arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatureClass, "filename", "TEXT", "","", "254")
  arcpy.CalculateField_management(outFeatureClass, "filename", str(shp), "PYTHON")
```

Then perform the append for each file in the new workspace.

What I'd like to do is be able to have a user drag and drop multiple shapefiles from multiple directories into a Multiple Value input box (like that in the Append tool).

I have two questions:

1. Is there an easier/better way to perform the task?
2. If not, what should I set the parameter type to (Multiple Value is not a selection).

Answer (score 7):

In your ArcToolbox tool properties I'd set the parameter to a FeatureLayer/FeatureDataset with MultiValue=Yes and use some code like the following to get the filename:

```
for shp in featureclasses.split(';'):
    dsc = arcpy.Describe(shp)
    filename=dsc.CatalogPath #unicode is returned
```

Comment: Right on!  Thank you so much, Luke.  I'll try it out.

Comment: Also, just to save yourself the headache of having to code and cleanup all those temporary datasets, consider copying the data into an [in_memory layer][1].  This 1) will be faster than writing it to disk and 2) automatically clean itself up.  Just replace your "outFeatureClass" line of code with "outFeatureClass = "in_memory\tmpSHP".  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000005s000000